# Webpack of Angular CLI build failing - Unexpected token

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-universal

I ejected an Angular Cli project, and tried to integrate Angular Universal into it. I've got the project bundling as it should. The problem is when I go to run "node dist/server.js", I get an `Unexpected Token` error.

Full error:

```
/Users/brandon.baker/Documents/Sites/brand-angular-seed/dist/server.js:405665
module.exports = ./../node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js;
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Webpack config:

```
// Work around for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts',
    // This is an example of Static prerendering (generative)
    prerender: './prerender.ts'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  // Make sure we include all node_modules etc
  externals: [
      /(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/,
      {
        'sqlite3': 'sqlite3',
        'mariasql': 'mariasql',
        'mssql': 'mssql',
        'mysql': 'mysql',
        'oracle': 'oracle',
        'strong-oracle': 'strong-oracle',
        'oracledb': 'oracledb',
        'pg': 'pg',
        'pg-query-stream': 'pg-query-stream',
        'hiredis': 'hiredis',
        'redis-parser': 'redis-parser',
        'fsevents': 'fsevents',
        'node-gyp': 'node-gyp'
      }
  ],
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

Maybe the solution is clear and I just don't know why this can't be resolved. It shouldn't be looking for a node_modules folder, right?

Comment: did it work before you did ng eject?  did you make any other changes?  it looks like that should be a string and start with a " or ' instead of ./  but I haven't seen that happen.  maybe you've missed quotes around a route in one of your configs?

Comment: maybe this line of code is not needed? just a guess. i've never seen it used before.  externals: [
      /(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/,

Comment: @Jesse It worked before I tried to integrate Angular Universal for server side rendering. From my understanding, that line is needed so that webpack doesn't process/bundle anything in node_modules.

Comment: i tried to include my webpack config but it's too long.  not sure if it will help any either

Comment: resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  modules: [
   path.resolve('./'),
   path.resolve('./node_modules')
  ],
  alias: {
     }
 },
 module: {
  rules: [
   // Ahead of Time Compilation
   { test: /\.ts$/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack', exclude: [/\.(spec)\.ts$/] },
   // AoT requires all files to be loaded
   { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
   { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
   {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[path][name].[ext]' }
   }
  ]
 },

Comment: there is a small snippet in hopes you'll find something worth trying

Comment: @blbaker Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug I did not. I gave up on implementing Angular Universal for now. Let me know if you figure something out!

Comment: @blbaker Thanks for replying so quickly. I ran into a similar issue and mine seems to have been related to my node_modules being in a non-standard location. Was yours too?

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug My node_modules folder is located in the root folder of the project so I don't think that is my issue. Is yours located in your project root?

Comment: @bibaker I actually had two node_modules folder for two different apps that I tried to combine (server and client components). I ended up combining them to a single package.json and a single node_modules that's in a common root directory. That works! :)

Comment: For anyone that might still read this, my problem was that I had some custom node scripts that were being packaged. Once I excluded those, webpack built just fine.

Comment: @blbaker can you provide more info? I'm facing the same problem and don't know what else to do.. I think that I'm including something like you that webpack doesn't like

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In my case, the cause of the problem was yarn workspace.

Including webpack related packages into `nohoist` resolved the issue.

```
"workspaces": {
  // ...
  "nohoist": [
    // ...
    "**/*webpack*" // <-
  ]
}
```